How to interface Raspberry Pi Pico with PyCharm (YOLOv8 object detection) for servo motor control via UART?
I am working on an object detection project using YOLOv8 in PyCharm (pure Python) on my laptop. I want to send a signal to my Raspberry Pi Pico via UART to control a servo motor when an object is detected. I have integrated MicroPython on the Pico to control the servo, but I am unsure how to establish communication between PyCharm and the Pico using PySerial. Tell me if my project is possible ! Thank you !
Components:
Laptop
RaspBerry Pi Pico
Servo Motor (2) MG 996r 0-120*
I have the following object detection code running on my laptop using PyCharm:
import cv2
import supervision as sv
from ultralytics import YOLO
import numpy as np
import serial
import time

# Initialize YOLOv8 model
model = YOLO('yolov8n.pt')

# Serial communication setup (adjust COM port)
ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600, timeout=1)
time.sleep(2)

object_class_ids = [39, 44, 42, 41]  # Bottle class IDs
CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD = 0.4

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)

bounding_box_annotator = sv.BoxAnnotator()
label_annotator = sv.LabelAnnotator()

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    if not ret:
        print("Failed to capture frame. Exiting.")
        break

    results = model.predict(frame)
    detections = sv.Detections.from_ultralytics(results[0])

    confidence_mask = detections.confidence > CONFIDENCE_THRESHOLD
    class_mask = np.isin(detections.class_id, object_class_ids)
    filtered_mask = np.logical_and(confidence_mask, class_mask)
    filtered_detections = detections[filtered_mask]

    if len(filtered_detections) > 0:
        print(f"Detected object(s): {filtered_detections}")
        ser.write(b'1')  # Send signal to Pico
        time.sleep(1)
        print("Sent signal to open the lid.")

        annotated_image = bounding_box_annotator.annotate(scene=frame, detections=filtered_detections)
        annotated_image = label_annotator.annotate(scene=annotated_image, detections=filtered_detections)
    else:
        annotated_image = frame

    cv2.imshow('Camera Feed with Annotations', annotated_image)

    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        print("'q' pressed, closing...")
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
ser.close()


On the Raspberry Pi Pico, I have this MicroPython code to control the servo motor:
import machine
import utime

# Setup servo motor
servo = machine.Pin(15, machine.Pin.OUT)
servo_pwm = machine.PWM(servo)
servo_pwm.freq(50)

def open_lid():
    print("Opening lid...")
    servo_pwm.duty_u16(7000)  # Move servo to open position
    utime.sleep(2)
    servo_pwm.duty_u16(0)  # Stop PWM signal to prevent jitter

# UART setup
uart = machine.UART(0, 9600)

print("Waiting for signals...")

while True:
    if uart.any():
        command = uart.read(1)  # Read 1 byte
        if command == b'1':
            print("Signal received! Opening lid.")
            open_lid()

I expected the servo to open when the object (bottle) is detected, but I am having trouble ensuring that the communication between my laptop (PyCharm) and the Raspberry Pi Pico is correctly established using UART.

Seems like a testing problem, not a programming one. Did you communicate with the microcontroller successfully (testing the microcontroller side/code) using a small program on your pc? And then in a next step the same, but with a very basic Python program of your own?

@Christoph Rackwitz, I am currently working on a project involving the Raspberry Pi Pico, where I have successfully implemented a MicroPython plugin and connected it with the Pico interpreter. During my testing, I was able to control an LED connected to pin 25 without any issues, which confirmed that my hardware setup is functioning correctly.

However, when I attempted to integrate the servo motor into the system, it did not respond as expected. Here are some details regarding my setup and the steps I have taken:

Hardware Configuration:


The servo motor is connected correctly according to the specifications.
I am using an MG996R servo motor, which I have tested individually to ensure it functions properly in Thonny IDE.



Code Integration:
I integrated the servo control code into my existing MicroPython script, which successfully operates the LED.
I ensured that the pin assignments for the servo motor were correct and that the control signals were being sent.



Testing Steps:
I verified that the power supply to the servo is adequate, as it requires a sufficient current to operate.
I conducted separate tests on the servo motor using a simple script, and it worked as intended.


Despite these efforts, the servo motor does not respond when integrated with the rest of the code. I suspect that there may be an issue with how the signals are being sent or processed within the integrated script.
I would appreciate any insights or suggestions you might have regarding this issue. Thank you for your assistance.
Best regards,

I would like to express that this is my first experience integrating projects using PyCharm. As a high school student working on a significant research project, I am eager to learn and improve my skills. However, with the approaching due date, I find myself struggling to grasp some of the complexities of coding. I appreciate your understanding and any guidance you can provide as I work to resolve these project.

Are you trying to open the lid for a duration of only two seconds?

no, i wanna do like 8-10 seconds open. but i tried the 2 seconds sleep to see if it can be open. btw do you have accessible account we can interact on?

welcome [tour] [ask] [mre] [help/on-topic] [help/dont-ask]

@Guillius, btw im using pyserial library now not UART since UART need 2 picos just to interact with other. in my case im only using 1 pico just to directly send a signal to my pico to control the servo, which in my case i dont know if its possible.

@Guillius would be possible to control a servo motor using pyserial?

https://robotics.stackexchange.com/
